# batch file to start Catalina.bat file

Tags: apache, batch-file, catalina

I want to create batch file to start/stop catalina.bat file on window server.

```
@echo off
cls

cd D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.75-windows-x86\apache-tomcat-7.0.75\bin

catalina.bat start
```

this is what I create but not working.

Comment: How is it not working? Are there any error messages or is it that nothing happens? Have you tried running your batch file from the `cmd.exe` window?

Comment: Typically we call a batch file. I suggest running this from cmdline first to ensure you do not have any `CATALINA_HOME` environment issues, if not it will work as is in a batch file.  `call "D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.75-windows-x86\apache-tomcat-7.0.75\bin\catalina.bat" start`

Comment: It worked.. sorry I was using some other argument

Comment: @KeshavKalra, given that you responded above after I'd posted my answer I'd appreciate it if you provided feedback please. The `Call` method is only really necessary if you are returning to the same batch file upong completion of `catalina.bat` otherwise there's nothing stopping you from running the batch file directly as you had.

Answer (score 0):

If you type `CD /?` at the command prompt you'll note it has a `/D` option for changing drives.

You could therefore try:

```bat
@Echo Off
ClS
CD /D "D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.75-windows-x86\apache-tomcat-7.0.75\bin"
catalina.bat start <args>
```

If you don't need to have your working directory as the `\bin` location you could just use:

```bat
@Echo Off
ClS
"D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.75-windows-x86\apache-tomcat-7.0.75\bin\catalina.bat" start <args>
```

To stop it, repeat the last line, ending it with `stop` instead of `start`

**Edit**

If you really do need to use it, and given that you said the `Call` command works, you could use…

Either:

```bat
@Echo Off
ClS

Rem start it
Call "D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.75-windows-x86\apache-tomcat-7.0.75\bin\catalina.bat" start <args>

Rem Do some other stuff
Timeout 120 >Nul

Rem stop it
Call "D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.75-windows-x86\apache-tomcat-7.0.75\bin\catalina.bat" stop
```

Or:

```bat
@Echo Off
ClS

Rem Make \bin directory current
CD /D "D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.75-windows-x86\apache-tomcat-7.0.75\bin"

Rem start it
Call catalina.bat start <args>

Rem Do some other stuff
Timeout 120 >Nul

Rem stop it
Call catalina.bat stop
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a `.bat` file to start your Tomcat, then here it goes:

1. Declare the JAVA_HOME & CATALINA `_HOME` path in the system environment variables.
2. Create a file in Notepad with the `.bat` extension and put the following code within the respective Tomcat directory:

   ```
   set JPDA_ADDRESS=8000
   set JPDA_TRANSPORT=dt_socket
   C:
   cd C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0 //Enter Your Tomacat Path
   call .\bin\catalina jpda start
   ```

[Check out the image attached for more detailed explanation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIoJe.png)